# add admob native ad in a recyclereview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, admob, firebase-admob

I am trying to ad the `admob's` native ad in a `recyclerview` fragment, which is displayed inside a `viewpager`.

My **fragment** looks like:

```
public class SunFragment extends Fragment {
  public static final int NUMBER_OF_ADS = 1;
  private AdLoader adLoader;
  private List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<UnifiedNativeAd> mNativeAds = new ArrayList<>();

  ArrayList<Object> sunsList;
  Typeface sunfont;
  Double Dlat;
  Double Dlang;

  //to be called by the MainActivity
  public SunFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }


  private static final String KEY_LOCATION_NAME = "location_name";
  public String TAG = "SunFragment";
  public String location;//="No location name found";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      location = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME).toString();
      }
    setRetainInstance(true);
    loadNativeAds();
    //MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    mRecyclerViewItems = this.getRecyclerViewItems();
  }
//  public List<Object> getRecyclerViewItems() {
//    return mRecyclerViewItems;
//  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sunsList = new ArrayList<>();
    sunsList.add(
        new SunSession(...//Populate sunsList one by one//...)
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sun, container, false);
    RecyclerView rv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
//    System.out.println("location  " + location);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new SunAdapter(getContext(), sunsList);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
  }


  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle locState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(locState);
    if (location != null) {
      locState.putCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME, location);
    }
  }

  public List<Object> getRecyclerViewItems() {
    return mRecyclerViewItems;
  }

  private void insertAdsInMenuItems() {
    if (mNativeAds.size() <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    int offset = (mRecyclerViewItems.size() / mNativeAds.size()) + 1;
    int index = 0;
    for (UnifiedNativeAd ad : mNativeAds) {
      mRecyclerViewItems.add(index, ad);
      index = index + offset;
    }
    //loadMenu();
  }

  private void loadNativeAds() {

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Here I am", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(getContext(), getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
    adLoader = builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(
        new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
            // A native ad loaded successfully, check if the ad loader has finished loading
            // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
            mNativeAds.add(unifiedNativeAd);
            if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
              insertAdsInMenuItems();
            }
          }
        }).withAdListener(
        new AdListener() {
          @Override
          public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // A native ad failed to load, check if the ad loader has finished loading
            // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
            Log.e("MainActivity", "The previous native ad failed to load. Attempting to"
                + " load another.");
            if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
              insertAdsInMenuItems();
            }
          }
        }).build();

    // Load the Native ads.
    adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), NUMBER_OF_ADS);
  }
}
```

and my **adapter** is:

```
public class SunAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  private final Context mContext;
  private final ArrayList<Object> mSunsList;
  private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
  private static final int UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;


  public SunAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> sunsList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mSunsList = sunsList;
  }

  public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView textViewId;
    private TextView textViewSicon;
    private TextView textViewStime;
    private TextView textViewEicon;
    private TextView textViewEtime;
    private TextView ntextViewSicon;
    private TextView ntextViewStime;
    private TextView ntextViewEicon;
    private TextView ntextViewEtime;

    MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      textViewId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
      textViewSicon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_MSicon);
      textViewStime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_MStime);
      textViewEicon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_MEicon);
      textViewEtime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_MEtime);
      ntextViewSicon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_NSicon);
      ntextViewStime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_NStime);
      ntextViewEicon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_NEicon);
      ntextViewEtime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_NEtime);
//    mSportsImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sportsImage);
    }
  }


  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return mSunsList.size();
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object sunList = mSunsList.get(position);
    if (sunList instanceof UnifiedNativeAd) {
      return UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
    return MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
  }

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
      case UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
        View unifiedNativeLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(
            viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_unified,
            viewGroup, false);
        return new UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder(unifiedNativeLayoutView);
      case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
        // Fall through.
      default:
        View menuItemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.card_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(menuItemLayoutView);
    }
  }

  // @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
      case UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
        UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mSunsList.get(position);
        populateNativeAdView(nativeAd, ((UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder) holder).getAdView());
        break;
      case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
        // fall through
      default:
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
        SunSession sunSession = (SunSession) mSunsList.get(position);
        myViewHolder.textViewId.setText(sunSession.getId());
        myViewHolder.textViewSicon.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(sunSession.getSicon(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        myViewHolder.textViewStime.setText(sunSession.getStime());
        myViewHolder.textViewEicon.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(sunSession.getEicon(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        myViewHolder.textViewEtime.setText(sunSession.getEtime());
        myViewHolder.ntextViewSicon.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(sunSession.getNSicon(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        myViewHolder.ntextViewStime.setText(sunSession.getNStime());
        myViewHolder.ntextViewEicon.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(sunSession.getNEicon(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        myViewHolder.ntextViewEtime.setText(sunSession.getNEtime());
    }
  }



  private void populateNativeAdView(UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd,
                                    UnifiedNativeAdView adView) {
    // Some assets are guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd.
    ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());
    ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeAd.getBody());
    ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAd.getCallToAction());

    // These assets aren't guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd, so it's important to
    // check before trying to display them.
    NativeAd.Image icon = nativeAd.getIcon();

    if (icon == null) {
      adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(icon.getDrawable());
      adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (nativeAd.getPrice() == null) {
      adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ((TextView) adView.getPriceView()).setText(nativeAd.getPrice());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getStore() == null) {
      adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ((TextView) adView.getStoreView()).setText(nativeAd.getStore());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getStarRating() == null) {
      adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      ((RatingBar) adView.getStarRatingView())
          .setRating(nativeAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
      adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (nativeAd.getAdvertiser() == null) {
      adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      ((TextView) adView.getAdvertiserView()).setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiser());
      adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // Assign native ad object to the native view.
    adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
  }
}
```

The ad has been initialized in `MainActivity` as:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id));
```

The code shows no error, and the SunList array (i.e. `MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE`) is shown properly.
But the ad view (i.e. UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE) is showing no sign, not even as a place holder.

The fragment is called by the MainActivity as a viewpager (as generated by default tabbed activity) as:

```
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this,
            getSupportFragmentManager(), Lat, Long);
```

What I am doing wrong here?

NB: I am using firebase

**Update**
I suspect,

```
 @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object sunList = mSunsList.get(position);
    if (sunList instanceof UnifiedNativeAd) {
      System.out.println("==================Hello==============");
      return UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
    return MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
  }
```

is never true. The string has never printed

**UPDATE** Probably I have found the problem, but don't know how to solve it:

If I change the `getItemViewType` as:

```
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object sunList = mSunsList.get(position);
//    if (sunList instanceof UnifiedNativeAd) {
    if (position%3==0){
      System.out.println("=================="+position+"==============");
      return UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
    return MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
  }
```

Then I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.phocast.ui.main.SunSession cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAd
```

In this line in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mSunsList.get(position);
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

you can load add when add show in recyclerview. not in activity

Answer (score 0):

I think your native is not loading properly.
1) Make sure your ads inserting in recycleview. add log in all method and confirm it is loading properly.

2) During test app use testing ads id.

3) After LoadAds update recycleview with

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

4) There is no issue in below method.

```
@Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object sunList = mSunsList.get(position);
    if (sunList instanceof UnifiedNativeAd) {
      System.out.println("==================Hello==============");
      return UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
    return MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
  }
```

If still not getting ads please let me know.

Comment: I do think the point 1 is the reason, but I dont know how to rectify this

Comment: yes...thats probably not the problem. Problem is, as in https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-android/#11, I dont know how to do this inside a viewpager adapter

Comment: @BaRud refer https://github.com/googlecodelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed

Comment: this is the same page from codelab I am referring :)

Comment: Then replace your code with example code. Thats it. By the way it is working perfectly for me.